# How to convert byte array to image in angular 6?

Tags: angular

I want to show an image with angular 6 and spring boot, but the picture is not displayed and I receive no error.

```
class Utilisateur{
    byte [] photo;
}

<img src="{{'data:image/jpg;base64,'+action.utilisateur.photo}}">
```

And in my back-end:

```
String encodebase64 = Base64.getEncoder().encoedToString(utilisateur.getPhoto());
utilisateur.setPhoto(encodebase64);
```

Comment: Have you tried narrowing down the problem with debugging? For instance, what is the value of the src attribute in the DOM at runtime?

Comment: `encoedTo` is it an error when recopying in the post or is it an error in your script ?

Comment: yes meriton but when i convert the same image with conertisser online i don't recieve the same code base64 its normaly ? or the problème it's with my code convert ?